# Is there any script or any automation?

Tags: python, bash, shell

Problem Statement : I am having 150 tiles(Directories) where I need to copy .hierdb file to specific path. Then I need to copy that .hierdb file to here sub_block_hierdb.lst.

For example :

```
-> cp -rf /proj/disk_2/HDC/PERFRO16_TSMCN7B1.ssgc.lib.gz_1786/hdc/hcdc_PERFRO16_TSMCN7B1.hierdb(source) src/meta/tools/2in/tiles/tile_1(tile_1 to tile_150)/.(destination)
-> gvim src/meta/tools/2in/tiles/tile_1/sub_block_hierdb.lst -> paste -> hcdc_PERFRO16_TSMCN7B1.hierdb
```

Having 150+ tiles can anyone please let me know how to script or automate. I need to copy .hierdb file to 150 tiles and paste in sub_block_hierdb.lst.

I have tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
srcdir="/proj/disk_2/HDC/PERFRO16_TSMCN7B1.ssgc.lib.gz_1786/hdc/hcdc_PERFRO16_TSMCN7B1.hierdb"
tiles=(tile_1 tile_2....tile_150)

for tile in "${tiles[@]}"
do
    dstdir="src/meta/tools/2in/tiles/$tile/."
    cp -rf $srcdir "$dstdir"
    echo "hcdc_PERFRO16_TSMCN7B1.hierdb" >> src/meta/tools/2in/tiles/$tile/sub_block_hierdb.lst
done
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210226/discussion-on-question-by-p-goutham-is-there-any-script-or-any-automation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
tiles=(tile_{1..150})
```

instead of

```
tiles=(tile_1 tile_2....tile_150)
```